# Difference between PIC16F877 and PIC16F877A?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

Is there any difference between PIC16F877 and PIC16F877A?? I checked the datasheet, but didn't get any answer.

From my experience, we can use 877 instead of 877A and vice verse.

Is there any situation we can't interchange these parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, I found a difference between these chips.

Please find the Page No:33 of the document DS39582B (which is the PIC16F87XA datasheet).
You can find few words in a box,

> Note: The self-programming mechanism for Flash
>   program memory has been changed. On
>   previous PIC16F87X devices, Flash programming
>   was done in single-word erase/
>   write cycles. The newer PIC18F87XA
>   devices use a four-word erase/write
>   cycle. See Section 3.6 “Writing to Flash
>   Program Memory” for more information.

I was using the PIC16F87X datasheet, and my flash write routines was not working. Finally I found the document and solved the bug.

I don't know whether there is some other difference.

Answer (score 4):

The A versions of Microchip devices are simply improved versions. You might see a difference if you examine the errata documents. They are usually cheaper.

There should be no problems if you interchange the two versions.

Microchip advises switching to the PIC16F887, from both devices. It's a much better chip, and is a lot cheaper than either of them.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But both 877 and 877A are available in microchip direct!!!

Comment: Of course they are, Microchip has a very good reputation of keeping older chips available. You can buy a 16F84 if you want (but no longer the 16C84). But when you start now I'd take the 887 or even a 16F1938. And yes, there are subtle differences between the 877 and 877A, like the added comparators.

Comment: Please find the answer.